# How to test online payment application?

Tags: asp.net, testing, credit-card

We have ASP.NET application where you can purchase something. Of course, at the end of process there's a screen where you have to populate credit card number and other standard stuff. But, we don't have any real credit card number and I can't pass that step to test it further.

How can I test it?

Comment: most payment gateways provide dummy card numbers for testing.

Comment: Thanks. But, where can I find such a dummy card numbers for Liqpay?

Comment: Is there any other way to test?

Comment: Except card number I need expiry date and control number with 3 digits.

Answer (score 3):

You can use http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/515367/Validate-credit-card-number-with-Mod-10-algorithm tutorial to understand better the credit card number theory and can apply the same in your application for testing.. Or, you can use any kind of payment gateways like PayPal to test.

Comment: Can I use PayPal payment gateways for Liqpay as well?

Comment: Dear @tesicg, Liqpay is also a payment gateway so you need have to get its API to integrate with your application and there must be some testing things for developers to test their application in sandbox mode. Talk to Liqpay support team for further information.